# Double exclamation mark on EditText setError when used on a password type field

Tags: android, android-edittext, androiddesignsupport, android-textinputlayout

In my application I use the Design Support Library's TextInputLayout around all my EditTexts that require the hint to label effect. However I noticed an adverse effect of doing so - applying it to a password field will make the setError method apply two exclamation marks: one in the middle of the EditText and one at the proper place, slightly covering the "eye" (password visibility) icon.

[image]

This only happens on fields that have the inputType set to textPassword.

How could I fix this?

EDIT:

XML layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"/>            
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: please post xml code.

Comment: Added the layout code!

Comment: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try to set your error message just for TextInputLayout and remove it from editText object.

Comment: But this changes the nature of error display. Can't we have a floating label at the end using set error for textinputlayout?

Comment: This changes the style of the error. I want to see both the eye and a error side by side, not the error icon over the eye. So, I think this is not the right answer. ATM, I didn't find any solution, just add your own ImageView...

Comment: @Cocorico Did you find any solution ? I'm trying to achieve the same thing but could not find any way to do it yet